# Moving an object continiously on Y axis but stop on the lowest position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was hoping you could help me to specify a condition to my task here:
I have an object (ball) moving up and down continiously. But I need to stop it for couple of seconds at the lowest point. I am using coroutine to perform that however my brain overloaded when trying to figre how to stop it. Here is my code so far:

```
private Vector3 startPosition;

private float curYPos = 0.0f;
private float curZRot = 0.0f;

public float amplitude = 1.0f;
public float rotationSpeed = 50;

void Start()
{
    startPosition = transform.position;
    StartCoroutine(GoUpAndDown());
}

void Update()
{
    curZRot += Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed;  //those two lines are not related to my question
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, curZRot);
}


IEnumerator GoUpAndDown()
{
    while (true)  // I believe I need to specify condition here, when the ball reach the low position, but your help would be appreciated here
    {
        while(true)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, startPosition.y + Mathf.Sin(Time.time * amplitude), transform.position.z);
            yield return null;
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I'm confused on your naming. The `amplitude` in your code doesn't change the amplitude (which is always +/- 1) but rather changes the frequency.

Well and then both your while loops are **endless** loops so the

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
```

can never be reached unless you somehow allow to exit that **inner** while, not the outer one.

Sinus performs one full cycle within `360°` or in radians `2π`.

[image]

Luckily the parameter of [`Mathf.Sin`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Sin.html) already is in radians. You could use this and simply wait until exactly one such cycle of `2π` has passed.

Additionally reduce/shift it by `-0.5π` (=`-90°`) since your cycle is supposed to go from `-1` to `-1` instead of from `0` to `0`.

So something like

```
IEnumerator GoUpAndDown()
{
    var startPosition = transform.position;
    var start = -0.5f * Mathf.Pi;
    var end = Mathf.Pi * 1.5f;

    while (true)
    {
        // timePassed will move linear from -0.5π to 1.5π
        var timePassed = start;
        while(timePassed < end)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, startPosition.y + Mathf.Sin(timePassed), transform.position.z);

            // Add time passed since last frame scaled by your "amplitude" value
            // Avoiding overshoot
            timePassed += Mathf.Min(Time.deltaTime * amplitude, end - timePassed);
            yield return null;
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this quick solution (though maybe something simpler can be done). You can record values of `Math.Sin` and compare the value you get now with previous value. You can notice that the oscillation changes direction from down to up when you had previously the value about `-0.99` and then something greater, say `-0.98`. So by checking that the previous value is lower, you know that your object is moving in upward direction. The first time this upward direction is detected you execute your waiting, and in order to prevent waiting from happening on the very next frame you also store a flag saying that "you've already waited on this oscillation".

When you detect the object moving downwards, that's where you can reset this flag in order to catch the next beginning of upward moving

Note that I'm writing it out of my head, so can't test if the syntax is all right and that it works completely as intended, so change something if it doesn't.

```
float prevYSin;
bool alreadyWaited = false;

IEnumerator GoUpAndDown()
{
    prevYSin = Mathf.Sin(Time.time);
    while(true)
    {
        var curYSin = Mathf.Sin(Time.time);
        if (!alreadyWaited && prevYSin < curYSin) // sin started to rise, and we haven't waited yet
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
            alreadyWaited = true;     
        }
        else if (prevYSin > curYSin) // sin started to fall, may reset that flag to wait next time
        {
            alreadyWaited = false;
        }
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, startPosition.y + amplitude * curYSin, transform.position.z);
        prevYSin = curYSin;
        yield return null;
    }
     
}
```